# XMPPFramework - Connect via SSL on Openfire

Tags: ios, ssl, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I'm trying to connect my users via **SSL** from my iOS XMPP chat client to Openfire server.

In my **iOS** client:

```
- (void)setupStream 
{
    ...
    // BOOL values for security settings
    customCertEvaluation = NO;
    allowSelfSignedCertificates = YES;
    allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO;
}
```

In my **Openfire** server's **Security Settings** > **Client Connection Security**, I've set:

`Required - Clients can only connect to the server using secured connections.`

Thus, the following delegate method will be called:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)settings 
{
    NSString *expectedCertName = [xmppStream.myJID domain];

    if (customCertEvaluation)
        [settings setObject:@(YES) forKey:GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust];

    if (allowSelfSignedCertificates)
        [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];

    if (allowSSLHostNameMismatch)
        [settings setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];

    else
        if (expectedCertName)
            [settings setObject:expectedCertName forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
}
```

I attempted this solution from this thread: [XMPPFramework TLS/SSL connection with Openfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876421/xmppframework-tls-ssl-connection-with-openfire)

However, when I run my application and attempt to connect to the server, I'd receive this error:

`Security option unavailable - kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot - You must use manual trust evaluation`

I looked through the `GCDAsyncSocket` class and realized `kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot` is stated as deprecated. An NSAssert was implemented to deliberately throw the error.

Next, I decided to change my BOOL values as such:

```
- (void)setupStream 
{
    ...
    // BOOL values for security settings
    // Manually evaluate trust
    customCertEvaluation = YES;
    allowSelfSignedCertificates = NO;
    allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO;
}
```

This time, again, no connection could be made to the server but, no error was prompted.

I could connect to Openfire fine if I changed the Client Connection Security back to the original setting > **Optional**. But, I wouldn't be connected via SSL as indicated by a *lock* icon beside every user's status in Client Sessions.

My Android client (using Smack API for XMPP) connects to Openfire via SSL without issues. So I'm wondering if there's workaround I have to implement for my iOS client using XMPPFramework.

I would greatly appreciate any advices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Explanation

In the latest version of XMPP ([after April 22](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/333#issuecomment-40996953)), you can **no longer** use `allowSelfSignedCertificates = YES` with the following:

```
if (allowSelfSignedCertificates)
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];`
```

This is because `kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot` & `SSLSetAllowsAnyRoot` have been deprecated.

```
 /* 
  * ==== The following UNAVAILABLE KEYS are: (with throw an exception)
  * - kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot (UNAVAILABLE)
  *     You MUST use manual trust evaluation instead (see GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust).
  *     Corresponding deprecated method: SSLSetAllowsAnyRoot
  */
```

See [XMPPFramework/GCDAsyncSocket.h](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Vendor/CocoaAsyncSocket/GCDAsyncSocket.h) & [Deprecated Secure Transport Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/secureTransportRef/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SSLSetAllowsAnyRoot).

---

### Solution

1. Go to Openfire server > Security Settings > Client Connection Security

   `Check: Required - Clients can only connect to the server using secured connections.`
2. Define variable in AppDelegate

   ```
   BOOL customCertEvaluation;
   ```
3. Set variable in setupStream

   ```
   - (void)setupStream 
   {
       ...
       customCertEvaluation = YES;
   }
   ```
4. Set security settings in willSecureWithSettings

   ```
   - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)settings
   {
       /*
        * Properly secure your connection by setting kCFStreamSSLPeerName 
        * to your server domain name
        */
       [settings setObject:xmppStream.myJID.domain forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];

       /*
        * Use manual trust evaluation
        * as stated in the XMPPFramework/GCDAsyncSocket code documentation
        */
       if (customCertEvaluation)
           [settings setObject:@(YES) forKey:GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust];
   }
   ```
5. Validate peer manually

   ```
   /*
    * This is only called if the stream is secured with settings that include:
    * - GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust == YES
    * That is, if a delegate implements xmppStream:willSecureWithSettings:, and plugs in that key/value pair.
    */
    - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveTrust:(SecTrustRef)trust completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL shouldTrustPeer))completionHandler
    {
        /* Custom validation for your certificate on server should be performed */

        completionHandler(YES); // After this line, SSL connection will be established
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, after i updated my XMPPFramework. After days of trying to find out what went wrong i came across this question, but the solution didn't work for me.

Here is what worked for me. The problem seems to originate from your **xmppStream.startTLSPolicy**. Setting  startTLSPolicy explicitly worked for me.

```
xmppStream.startTLSPolicy = XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyPreferred; // or
xmppStream.startTLSPolicy = XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyRequired;
```

**Here is an EXPLANATION of why it works.**

In XMPPStream's handleStreamFeatures method, it turns out that. If your XMPP Server doesn't return starttls as 'required' and you don't set startTLSPolicy(default=XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyAllowed) explicitly. The client will just do a normal connection and not a TLS one.

Here is section of code(for reference) in XMPPStream that is doing the checks.

```
/**
 * This method is called anytime we receive the server's stream features.
 * This method looks at the stream features, and handles any requirements so communication can continue.
**/
- (void)handleStreamFeatures
{
    NSAssert(dispatch_get_specific(xmppQueueTag), @"Invoked on incorrect queue");

    XMPPLogTrace();

    // Extract the stream features
    NSXMLElement *features = [rootElement elementForName:@"stream:features"];

    // Check to see if TLS is required
    // Don't forget about that NSXMLElement bug you reported to apple (xmlns is required or element won't be found)
    NSXMLElement *f_starttls = [features elementForName:@"starttls" xmlns:@"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"];

    if (f_starttls)
    {
        if ([f_starttls elementForName:@"required"] || [self startTLSPolicy] >= XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyPreferred)
        {
            // TLS is required for this connection

            // Update state
            state = STATE_XMPP_STARTTLS_1;

            // Send the startTLS XML request
            [self sendStartTLSRequest];

            // We do not mark the stream as secure yet.
            // We're waiting to receive the <proceed/> response from the
            // server before we actually start the TLS handshake.

            // We're already listening for the response...
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (![self isSecure] && [self startTLSPolicy] == XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyRequired)
    {
        // We must abort the connection as the server doesn't support our requirements.

        NSString *errMsg = @"The server does not support startTLS. And the startTLSPolicy is Required.";
        NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:errMsg forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];

        otherError = [NSError errorWithDomain:XMPPStreamErrorDomain code:XMPPStreamUnsupportedAction userInfo:info];

        // Close the TCP connection.
        [self disconnect];

        // The socketDidDisconnect:withError: method will handle everything else
        return;
    }

    // Check to see if resource binding is required
    // Don't forget about that NSXMLElement bug you reported to apple (xmlns is required or element won't be found)
    NSXMLElement *f_bind = [features elementForName:@"bind" xmlns:@"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"];

    if (f_bind)
    {
        // Start the binding process
        [self startBinding];

        // We're already listening for the response...
        return;
    }

    // It looks like all has gone well, and the connection should be ready to use now
    state = STATE_XMPP_CONNECTED;

    if (![self isAuthenticated])
    {
        [self setupKeepAliveTimer];

        // Notify delegates
        [multicastDelegate xmppStreamDidConnect:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use outdated API, check iPhoneXMPP sample for the new one - https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/commit/73f3c35a930b91d27e62bc19e91d9cdcc02c6e42

Comment: Nope, I'm using the latest API. That's why I've got `kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot` deprecated. Old API, specifically before April still uses it. Instead, I'm using an old solution in my question above. I read the issues page in XMPPFramework Github - after support for SSL Pinning was introduced, old Apple deprecated methods is no longer supported since April 22. See https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/333. Anyway, I've worked out a solution. Will share it here after more testing is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
customCertEvaluation = YES;
allowSelfSignedCertificates = YES;
allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO;
```

try these this might help

Comment: Please explain why this "might help".

Comment: Because it worked for me!!! .May be the reason for not establishing a connection is because the allowSelfSignedCertifates function should be set to yes, Only then certificates are allowed for signing for a secure connection. Try this,nothing wrong in giving it a try.

Comment: @v1shnu.mee You're most likely using an outdated API. Because your corresponding method for allowSelfSignedCertificates has been deprecated. Check out my answer above.

Comment: @KeithOYS Can you explain how actually certificate is created and how it is transferred.How do we see if the connection is secure.

Comment: @v1shnu.mee See: Create a self-signed server certificate - https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/ssl-guide.html | If a user is connected via SSL, you'll see a lock icon beside the user's name in Sessions page.

Comment: @KeithOYS If i do all the steps listed in the link will it be enough or should i do any code change.I am new to this so bare me.What to do for a TLS connection

Comment: @v1shnu.mee In Openfire, ensure that you create a self-signed certificate (preferable to follow the steps in the link). In Xcode, you may perform the code changes according to my answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57078/discussion-between-v1shnu-mee-and-keith-oys).

Comment: @KeithOYS thanks for your time dude.hope this solves my doubt and help the actually poster too.

Comment: @v1shnu.mee Sure about that. :)