# XMPPFramework - Secure Messaging

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am trying to implement XMPP in my app to allow message passing (Chat application). I need the message to be secured. I tried searching for it but only little help.I think there is a way to pass certificates with servers but don't know how to do that. Is there a way to do this? What should i add in my code? Any certificates?

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMPPFramework TLS/SSL connection with Openfire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876421/xmppframework-tls-ssl-connection-with-openfire)

Comment: allowSelfSignedCertificates = YES; allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO;      I found this line from the link you posted. but where should i add that.are these two lines alone is sufficient ??.Should i import any frame works, sorry i am new to these so spare me. @legoscia

Comment: Check out: [XMPPFramework - Connect via SSL on Openfire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298917/xmppframework-connect-via-ssl-on-openfire)